Script added to `svelte:head` ends up being included twice
In my root +layout.svelte file I have the following code:
<svelte:head>
  {#if environment === "PRODUCTION"}
    <script defer data-domain="mydomain.com" src="https://plausible.io/js/script.js"></script>
  {/if}
</svelte:head>

This ends up twice in the web page. How can I make sure that this is not duplicated? Ideally I would just add this to my app.html and not deal with svelte:head, but since this should only be loaded on production, I need the flexibility of conditionals...
Because this script ends up being included twice, all events that we track get counted twice 

I'm guessing this might be the case when you support server-side rendering. I'm not completely sure how hydration works in SvelteKit, but I imagine the web browser might first the rendered HTML code and send one HTTP request, and then after hydration (having run the SPA in the web browser), it sends another one. To test, add also browser to your condition. If my theory is correct, then it should only load that <script> once in the browser. I'm not saying this is a good solution for you, but try it for testing ^^

Yeah, that did indeed work. Weird that this is necessary.

Since it's dynamic, I guess it has to be re-evaluated when hydrating, for example because browser have different values on the server and the client. And usually it's not a problem to load the same JS file again. But if you misuse its intended purpose (i.e. use it for tracking), then of course it can screw things up. Maybe you can do it better using transformPageChunk in handle().

Your original idea to add this script to your root html file is, I believe, the correct approach.
Basically, this is a script you will want to include whenever you build for production, and never include in development, so a mechanism that would deal with this during the build step is the desired solution. One such mechanism is to maintain 2 versions of your root html file (dev vs. prod) and use the right one depending on context. Another possible mechanism would be to inject extra content (such as your <script> tag) during the build step (or alternatively, whenever you run in production mode).
According to this discussion you have two options, both of which I believe give you the ability to implement either mechanism:

use the transformIndexHtml plugin (the discussion linked to above shows examples)
use vite-plugin-html-config which itself uses transformIndexHtml internally but might be simpler/clearer to configure

Good luck!

Turning Peppe's comment into an answer, this is what I went with:
<script>
  import { browser } from "$app/environment";
</script>

<svelte:head>
  {#if environment === "PRODUCTION" && !browser}
    <script defer data-domain="mydomain.com" src="https://plausible.io/js/script.js"></script>
  {/if}
</svelte:head>

